# помогите вывести 10 вместо 30

Tags: pascal

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тут в конце вывод должен быть 10, а не 30

```
var
k,i:integer;
begin
readln(i);
k:=0;
for i:= 10 to 99 do begin 
if (i mod 3=0) then k:=k+1; end; write(k)

end.
```

Comment: Почерк кривой, ничего не разобрать.

Comment: @Эникейщик поправил

Comment: Замените `write(k);` на `write(10);` и будет Вам 10. Ну или объясните, по какому принципу должно получиться 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл for должен быть до 39 , тогда будет 10

```
k,i:integer;
begin
readln(i);
k:=0;
for i:= 10 to 39 do begin 
if (i mod 3=0) then k:=k+1; end; write(k)

end.
```

Comment: Почему именно до 39? Можно и до 40 и до 41. Можно заменить еще пару значений

Comment: Можно и 40 и 41, ответ будет такой же, но у него 99 конечное значение  и оно нацело делится на 3 , логически взял 39, также k зависит только от цикла фор , как у него написанно в программе

Comment: непонятно, каком образом должно получиться 10. Можно заменить i mod 3 на i mod 9, тоже напечатается 10. Можно написать k:=-20. Можно просто написать write(10) и напишется 10. Задача неясна, тут не очень поощряются ответы на такие невнятные вопросы.